# Analyzing results of using dir() on a Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array a.

When I use dir() on numpy array as follows:

```
dir(a)
```

I get the following list:

```
 '__abs__',
 '__add__',
 '__and__',
 '__array__',
 '__array_finalize__',
 '__array_function__',
 '__array_interface__',
 '__array_prepare__',
 '__array_priority__',
 '__array_struct__',
 '__array_ufunc__',
 '__array_wrap__',
 '__bool__',
 '__class__',
 '__complex__',
 '__contains__',
 '__copy__',
 '__deepcopy__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__delitem__',
 '__dir__',
 '__divmod__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__float__',
 '__floordiv__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__iadd__',
 '__iand__',
 '__ifloordiv__',
 '__ilshift__',
 '__imatmul__',
 '__imod__',
 '__imul__',
 '__index__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__int__',
 '__invert__',
 '__ior__',
 '__ipow__',
 '__irshift__',
 '__isub__',
 '__iter__',
 '__itruediv__',
 '__ixor__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lshift__',
 '__lt__',
 '__matmul__',
 '__mod__',
 '__mul__',
 '__ne__',
 '__neg__',
 '__new__',
 '__or__',
 '__pos__',
 '__pow__',
 '__radd__',
 '__rand__',
 '__rdivmod__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__rfloordiv__',
 '__rlshift__',
 '__rmatmul__',
 '__rmod__',
 '__rmul__',
 '__ror__',
 '__rpow__',
 '__rrshift__',
 '__rshift__',
 '__rsub__',
 '__rtruediv__',
 '__rxor__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setitem__',
 '__setstate__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__sub__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__truediv__',
 '__xor__',
 'all',
 'any',
 'argmax',
 'argmin',
 'argpartition',
 'argsort',
 'astype',
 'base',
 'byteswap',
 'choose',
 'clip',
 'compress',
 'conj',
 'conjugate',
 'copy',
 'ctypes',
 'cumprod',
 'cumsum',
 'data',
 'diagonal',
 'dot',
 'dtype',
 'dump',
 'dumps',
 'fill',
 'flags',
 'flat',
 'flatten',
 'getfield',
 'imag',
 'item',
 'itemset',
 'itemsize',
 'max',
 'mean',
 'min',
 'nbytes',
 'ndim',
 'newbyteorder',
 'nonzero',
 'partition',
 'prod',
 'ptp',
 'put',
 'ravel',
 'real',
 'repeat',
 'reshape',
 'resize',
 'round',
 'searchsorted',
 'setfield',
 'setflags',
 'shape',
 'size',
 'sort',
 'squeeze',
 'std',
 'strides',
 'sum',
 'swapaxes',
 'take',
 'tobytes',
 'tofile',
 'tolist',
 'tostring',
 'trace',
 'transpose',
 'var',
 'view']
```

Now, I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to separate the attributes and methods from the above list automatically? I mean is there a method that can just output a list of methods only or attributes only of the numpy array.
2. There is dunder method __ len __ in the list but there is no len() in the list outputted as a result of dir(a). Why?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on 1.

Comment: Since `ndarray` is built from compiled code, the distinction between attribute and method isn't quite as clear as if you wrote the class in put Python.  Also many attributes are properites, or property-like, meaning using them actually calls a method.

Comment: Why do you need this.  All the public ones are documented: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html.  The `__...` ones are usually not used directly by users.  Python converts a `len(x)` to `x.__len__()` call, `+` results in a `__add__` or '__iadd__' etc call.

Comment: The `itpython` completion tool (tab) lists all these items ('__' separately), and appends a `()` to methods.

Comment: I am learning numpy so I thought it would be a good idea to get all the attributes and methods associated with numpy array.

Comment: I keep an `ipython` session (or several) running, where I can look at functions or method, and test code.  Its tab completion and `?` (doc) and `??` (code) utilities are invaluable.  But I also reference the online docs, such as the page I linked above.  `numpy` docs often include a `[source]` tab.  But a lot of `numpy` is compiled, so you can't read (readily) all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is dunder method __ len __ in the list but there is no len() in the list outputted as a result of dir(a). Why?

`__len__()` implements `len()`.

> Is there a way to separate the attributes and methods from the above list automatically? I mean is there a method that can just output a list of methods only or attributes only of the numpy array.

For attributes, you can do `vars(a)`.

For methods you can do:

```
methods = [method_name for method_name in dir(a)
                  if callable(getattr(a, method_name))]
```

In the code snippet above you would be creating a list of strings that represent the name of the methods by checking to see if `object.method_name` is callable.

If you wanted non-dunder methods, then you can add the following modification:

```
def is_dunder(name):
    if (
        len(name) > 4 and 
        name[:2] == name[-2:] == '__'
    ):
        return True
    else:
        return False

non_dunder_methods = [
    method_name for method_name in a if 
    not is_dunder(method_name) and callable(getattr(a, method_name))
]
```

Comment: If I do vars(), I get the following error: "vars() argument must have __ dict __ attribute"

Comment: The above is a recipe for getting attributes and methods from objects. However, I didn't realize the nuance of numpy objects that @hpaulj pointed out - so I would go with their answer.